# Return full field text with Lucene Highlighter

Tags: lucene, highlighting

How would I the full text instead of just a snippet when highlighting a field using the [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html) class? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighter's fragmenter governs the generation of snippets (fragments) that are returned.  You can use the [`NullFragmenter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/NullFragmenter.html) to have it use the entire content of the field:

```
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new NullFragmenter());
```